# efficient way to store and compare all elemets

Tags: java, performance

I've a `List<Solution> data = new ArrayList<Solution>();` which holds user information's.`Solution` contain user email,address,orderid and credit card information and deal id and  I want to find out the duplicate data(same deal id and same email address). So, I have to compare all data's and I did this

```
int totalNumberOfData = data.size();
int counter;
for (counter = 0; counter < totalNumberOfData; counter++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < totalNumberOfData; j++) {
        boolean faurdFound;
        faurdFound = isFaurdDeal(counter, j);
        if (faurdFound == true) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like know:

1. For data comparing, if this solution is efficient or is there any better way to implement this solution?
2. I am using `List` for store data.If I use `HashMap` instead of `List`. Will it be efficient? `HashMap` don't follow ordering.But, I have to maintain the order. What can be the better solution for this problem?

Comment: Look at `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: A side note: Don't obfuscate you code by separating declaration and initialization. This is not pascal.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution has a quadratic computational complexity. It basically means that the time it consumes is proportional to the square of your list size. You can read about Big-O notation to learn about more formalized view of this characteristic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Using `LinkedHashMap` with properly overriden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of `Solution` you can reach linear complexity, because checking for existence will be done in a constant time.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of the complexity and why using a `HashMap` will help :)

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` or `HashSet` will allow much faster checks for whether they contain an object as it does not need to scan every object in the list. The catch is that you need to identify the correct key ahead of time but so long as you can do that they will work well.

If you need ordering you can use a `TreeMap` (which will keep the elements sorted) or a `LinkedHashMap` (which will keep the elements in the order in which they are added).